# efficiently limiting for...in loop to specific property keys

Tags: javascript

I have a function that loop through nested objects that contain precompiled regex patterns.  It checks each pattern against a string, and if it matches, it does a replace using the "abriv" value.

The code works but I notice when examining the loop in debug mode that both the 'regex' and the 'abriv' property is being checked against the string.

How do I optimize this loop to only loop through the 'regex' values when its conducting the second for...in?  I tried using accessors like 'prop.regex' in loop but that doesnt seem to work.

```js
var car = /(\bauto\b|\bvehicle\b|\bride\b)/ig
var bus = /(\bcoach\b)/ig
var train = /(\bexpress\b|\brail\b)/ig

var regexList = {
  car: {
    abriv: 'car',
    regex: car
  },
  bus: {
    abriv: 'bus',
    regex: bus
  },
  train: {
    abriv: 'train',
    regex: train
  }
}

var testString = "I drove the auto";

function replacer(text) {
  for (var regex in regexList) {
    var obj = regexList[regex];
    for (var prop in obj) {

      if (obj.regex.test(text) === true) {
        this.text = text.replace(obj.regex, obj.abriv);
        return this;
      }
    }

  }
}

replacer(testString);
```

Comment: In your second loop, you loop over prop in obj, `for (var prop in obj)`, but never actually use prop.

Comment: Also, *this* is not set so `this.text` references the *text* property of the global object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't even need your second loop.

```
function replacer(text) {
  for (var regex in regexList) {
    var obj = regexList[regex];
      if (obj.regex.test(text) === true) {
        this.text = text.replace(obj.regex, obj.abriv);
        return this;
      }
  }
}
```

Is there something missing here ?

Comment: You're right. I modified the regexList structure and forgot to update the function.  Thanks - I feel silly.  I guess its time to get some sleep :)

Comment: As for the OP:  *this* is not set so `this.text` references the *text* property of the global object and the global object is returned. Perhaps it should be `text = text.replace(...)` and `return text`?

Comment: @RobG I actually have this as part of a larger function where I'm method chaining, I didn't adjust the 'this' reference when I modified the code for my SO post. But yes, you are correct given the context above.